# Angular + VB.NET - Routing not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, vb.net

So I'm working on a project which uses AngularJS and a Web API written in VB.NET
All of this works fine untill we have to maintain the routing.

The following code is from my angularApp, which defines the routing.

```
var angularApp = angular.module('AngularApp', ['ngRoute']);
    angularApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/ExpenseOverview', {
                controller: 'ExpenseOverviewController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/ExpenseOverview.aspx'
            })
            .when('/AddExpense',
            {
                controller: 'AddExpenseController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/AddExpense.aspx'
            })
            .when('/ApproveExpense',
            {
                controller: 'AddExpenseController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/ApproveExpense.aspx'
            })
            .when('/Organogram', {
                controller: 'AddExpenseController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/Organogram.aspx'
            })
            .when('/AddType', {
                controller: 'AddExpenseController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/AddType.aspx'
            })
            .when('/ExpenseEvidence', {
                controller: 'AddExpenseController',
                templateUrl: 'Angular/Views/ConfirmExpenseEvidence.aspx'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/ExpenseOverview' });
    }]);
```

***EDIT*** *I used .aspx pages because I wanted to use some code behind. If necessairy, I'll change them to static HTML files.*

Everything works fine on startup, the routing works as it was programmed to.
[image: Startup routing]

Next to that, when I navigate to other pages, the routing still works like expected. 
[image: Navigation works fine - URL changed with routing]

But from that point on, when I navigate back to the main form with the back button from Chrome, it all falls apart.

When I click on this button to navigate to another page (label is in Dutch), the routing isn't even triggered. This button is a simple HTML5 button and I also tried with a simple  tag. It just triggers a postback (sort of, the screen flashes for a second) and nothing happens.
[image: Button navigating to another page]

So in an attempt to reset everything, I tried to reload the page and this is what becomes of my URL:
[image: URL after reloading the page]

And after navigating to another page, it just changes the "#/???" part of my URL, which basically means that my routing is changed completely and I have no clue what is causing this.

Can anyone elaborate on this problem? Maybe an explanation about what I am doing wrong? If it's because of the .aspx pages, I'll need to find a solution on how to work with ResourceFiles on views that are written in HTML.

Comment: `templateUrl` is supposed to point to a static resource...why is it pointing to an aspx page?

Comment: I agree, the templates should be static HTML pages. I can't be sure that's causing this particular problem, though. The URL should be updating to `/ExpenseOverview` already, not just when you press the back button. Is the address bar updating each time you navigate?

Comment: The reason I used .aspx pages was because we wanted to use code behind on some of them. I don't know it that's such a big problem, could it be that all of this was caused by using .aspx instead of static HTML?